# Convert the Text file containing associative key value in to array and display in html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

The text file contains the below array.

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"Test Report",
      "htmlpath":"C:\\sample.html",
      "browser":"phantomjs",
      "browser_version":"2.1.1",
      "time":"0h 0min 0s5",
      "testresults":"passed: 1 failed: 0 skipped: 2"
   }
]

[  
   {  
      "title":"Test Report",
      "htmlpath":"C:\\sample1.html",
      "browser":"internet explorer",
      "browser_version":"11",
      "time":"0h 0min 0s8",
      "testresults":"passed: 1 failed: 0 skipped: 2"
   }
]
```

I would like to read the above text file using Javascript, parse it as an associative array.
Use this array and create a table for the Key value pair and display in the HTML.
Please help with the existing code to achieve this.

Comment: Is this supposed to be two arrays of one object each?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file shows how to read a file

Comment: what ur effort?? what code did u write ??

Comment: This is not a free coding service; people are generally not going to be willing to just write your program for you.  If you show what you've tried already, or give some evidence that you've at least attempted to tackle the problem, you're much likelier to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a server in order to read a file. Browsers don't give direct access to the filesystem (that would be a HUGE security issue).

With NodeJS, you can read and parse a JSON in a text file, like this :

```
readFile("mydata.json", (error, text) => console.log( JSON.parse(text) ) )
```

Then, iterate over your json data and build a table with whatever framework you want (jQuery, Angular, etc)